# File Caching enabled on Glassfish does not come in to effect

Tags: java, caching, glassfish-3, grizzly, httplistener

I have configured a new Network Listener and have a dedicated thread pool attached to the network listener. The thread pool will serve binary files of the size of 50MB to the clients. To improve performance, I have enabled File-Caching (Network Listeners -> File Cache). I have been doing testing with the File Caching flag enabled/disabled to see the difference in the performance. I don't see any difference in the performance at all. Using asadmin, I monitored the caching options (see attached) and I don't see any activity in there. Is anyone aware as to how I need to get this in to play? Below are the caching options I tuned.

```
File Caching
Status - Enabled
Max Age - 14400 seconds (4 hours)
Max Cache Size - 62914560 (60 MB)
Max File Count - 3
```

The configuration is deliberate as the files are static files and there will be bulk download requests for the same file.

[image: part]

[image]